# rabbitmq - how to remove an RPC message if it could not be delivered

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying RPC with RabbitMQ.

I noticed that if a client tries to send an RPC message to an RPC queue, and that there is no receiver to read the message(=> a timeout occurs in the client when it waits for the response), the message stays in the queue.

How can I have the RPC message removed from the queue if it could not be delivered (e.g.: a timeout occured, because the receiver is not started for example) ?

Is there a parameter at the message level, the channel level or the connection level ? If it exists, I did not find it in 2 days...

May be the message can be acknowledged by the client itself (after TryTake() has returned false because of a timeout) ?

if ever it is useful, I use the C# library.

Comment: Like this? https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

Comment: Thank you! I have just found this parameter too. I will try it now.